Do I need a comma before "or when a higher-priority process needs attention"?
Context:
(What I originally wrote.)

Context switching allows computers to efficiently run multiple processes. It happens when the operating system decides that the current running process has used up its allocated time on the CPU or when a higher-priority process needs attention.

vs
(What someone corrected.)

Context switching allows computers to efficiently run multiple processes. It happens when the operating system decides that the current running process has used up its allocated time on the CPU, or when a higher-priority process needs attention.

Question:
I think the clause "when a higher-priority process needs attention" is dependent because it relies on the main clause, "It happens," to make sense. On its own, it doesn't form a complete thought, so I think it doesn't need a comma before "or" because when an independent clause is followed by a dependent clause, a comma is usually unnecessary. However, they put a comma before "or." I want grammatical explanations.

Forget about 'rules' about dependent clauses and so on. If I was reading that sentence aloud, I would make a slight pause before 'or', so I would automatically put a comma there in writing (in the same way that I used one in this sentence).

What @KateBunting said. Except I probably wouldn't include the comma unless I was "deleting" the predictably-repeated second instance of when (either mechanism alone should suffice to make the text easily parseable, there's no need for both). But it's just a stylistic choice.

Why was this closed? This is not an opinion question. If it is a choice, then an objective answer might say 'it is in free variation, some people do it and some don't for no reason at all'. -That- is an objective answer. If it is a style question, what style recommends it and what style does not recommend it? What do style guides say?

They didn't explain clearly why they closed it, and I also want to know if there are any style guides about this.

"when a dependent clause is followed by an independent clause, it doesn't need a comma": it doesn't need a comma but a comma is often used.

I think you should coordinate on the verbs, highlighting the O/S as subject, instead of coordinating on "when":  "It happens when the operating system decides that the current process has used up its allocated time on the CPU or interrupts the current process on behalf of one with higher priority".

@TimR yes, the trouble lies with the verbs. Decides just doesn't work in the original.

This question is similar to: Comma before "and", "or" and other coordinating conjunctions in compound sentences ... necessary or not?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // '... when V1 happens and/or when V2 happens' similarly has an optional comma. Parsabality and readability are not to be dismissed, though: longer strings are often ...

best tidily corralled.

In a comment, Kate Bunting wrote:

Forget about 'rules' about dependent clauses and so on. If I was reading that sentence aloud, I would make a slight pause before 'or', so I would automatically put a comma there in writing (in the same way that I used one in this sentence).


I want grammatical explanations.

There are none. Although your comma may not be strictly necessary, it makes the sentence easier to read and understand, and is therefore a good stylistic choice.

@cdleace: Sometimes, commas are more or less compulsory. As you say, this is not an independent clause, and so the comma is not compulsory. However, in many cases a comma is optional. Then people like to add one if it makes the sentence easier to read. That is the case here.

I want grammatical explanations? Good to know. Point here is that writing is for the reader. If you can help organize your thoughts so the reader does less work, your explanations rise to a higher level than good grammar alone can produce.
